# How to create setup which will install framework during setup run

Tags: .net, windows-installer, prerequisites

How to create setup windows application develop in vs2012. Setup will install .net framework automatically during setup run. How to create this kind of setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with MSI or ClickOnce. Pre-requisites dialog lets you choose the dotnet framework that you want to get installed automatically.

If you're using ClickOnce, right-click on your project and choose Properties. In the Publish tab, you can see Pre-requisites button which will list different versions of .NET Framework among other components. Marking any of these components will install that component prior to installing your application.

If you're using MSI, you need a add a new Setup Project to your solution. Then use the same procedure as above to add a .NET Framework pre-requisite.

FYI, all versions of Windows now-a-days already include .NET Framework 2.0 or higher. If you're not using any library other than thee framework itself, you could even consider distributing the executable of your application (from bin folder) instead of creating an installer.

Comment: Or you could try wix setups which is now the preferred way of creating setups inside vs .